# What is the annual data volume produced by the individual Sentinel satellite missions?

Tags: data, sentinel-2, sentinel-1, copernicus

I am wondering how big the volume of the data produced by Sentinel-1, Sentinel-2 etc. in a given year. For Sentinel-1, it'd be most interesting to know the data volume of all SLC images, for Sentinel-2 the data volume of all granules.

Does anybody know a source where one can find these numbers?

Comment: If this is open data then the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: There are some numbers in the Annual data access report: https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/pub/SciHubWebPortal/AnnualReport2017/COPE-SERCO-RP-17-0186_-_Sentinel_Data_Access_Annual_Report_2017-Final_v1.4.1.pdf (---> 3,58 Petabytes in 2017)

Comment: and here: http://copernicus.eu/sites/default/files/documents/News/Data_Access_Functional_Requirements_Dec2016.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a pretty exact way to answer this question. It exploits the sentinelsat Python API to extract the desired information directly from ESA's SciHub:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI
api = SentinelAPI('yourUsername','yourPassword')
S1 = api.query(date=('2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','2017-12-31T23:59:59Z'),platformname='Sentinel-1',producttype='SLC',sensoroperationalmode='IW')
api.get_products_size(S1)
S2 = api.query(date=('2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','2017-12-31T23:59:59Z'),platformname='Sentinel-2',producttype='S2MSI1C')
api.get_products_size(S2)
```

This gives you 2.07 Petabyte of Sentinel-1 IW SLC data (ignoring GRD data, which was derived from the SLC data, as well as ignoring the non-standard acquisition modes). It would also give you the Sentinel-2 Level-1C data (ignoring Level-2A data and other non-standard products), but I currently don't have time for the data catalogue being downloaded. Nevertheless, I consider this a pretty good estimate for the annually produced data volume. If one has a different definition of annually produced data volume, it's easily possible to use different search parameters or no search parameters besides platformname at all.

EDIT: I finished the check now and want to include it to the answer for sake of completeness: Apparently, for 2017 there are 0.94 PetaByte of Sentinel-2 L1C data in the archive. Thus, one year's worth of standard Sentinel-1/Sentinel-2 data can be estimated to take about 3 PetaByte of storage.

Comment: Keep in mind that this number is projected to increase due to the improved downlink capabilities by using the relay satellite [EDRS-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Data_Relay_System).

Comment: But is that a unit of a volume?